# How to create views automatically from model as in Django admin?

Tags: django, view, web-frameworks, scaffolding, model-driven-development

I'm starting to use Django and I'm really impressed by the possibility of automatically creating views from a model.
So, I'd like to know if there is such functionality on other web frameworks. I know of RoR scaffolding, but that is not quite the same thing, since you need to change your views manually in case you change the related model.

Comment: As pointed by Gerard's link, the feature is called "Generic views".

Comment: In Rails 3 there is an alternative called "generic actions" [http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/20/generic-actions-in-rails-3/][1]


  [1]: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/20/generic-actions-in-rails-3/

Comment: Another alternative I've found are using css layout generation tools. For Ruby on Rails there are compass and blueprint. This post explain how to use them http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2010/11/how-blueprint-and-compass-help-idiots-making-css-layouts/

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for an answer here, perhaps django-baker (https://github.com/krisfields/django-baker.git) will do what you need.

```
pip install django-baker
```

Then add **django_baker** to INSTALLED_APPS and run

```
python manage.py bake your_app_name
```

Note that previously you need to remove urls.py and views.py from your app so they can be generated.

Then it will generate all the skeleton stuff.

Comment: This does not addresses directly the question here asked but adds related info and could be of help to others.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found one possible solution. The concept is called model drive development. There are quite a few java frameworks that provide the ability to create a, rather simple, application directly from the model. This post presents some of them http://www.javaneverdie.com/java-frameworks/java-domain-driven-frameworks-review/